# TFS XAML Build Console App

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, tfs, console-application

I'm using TFS2017 and VS2015.
I have a solution with multiple WebApps and a ConsoleApp.

When I do a TFS build I get the WebApps built and dropped to the location I need. but so far I have been manually copying the ConsoleApp.

Is there a way for TFS to build the ConsoleApp and also drop it in a specific location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you have to use the Xaml build system? See [Why You Should Switch to Build VNext](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/why-you-should-switch-to-build-vnext)

In TFS 2017 you can easily use the new vNext system to build the ConsoleApp and drop it in a specific location.

You can build the entire solution with **VS build task** or separately build the ConsoleApp projects with the **MSBuild task** with the MSBuild Arguments set e.g : `/p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`

Then use the **Publish Build Artifacts** task to drop it in the specific location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PowerShell script as [post build script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn376353%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in a xaml build and use it to copy files to the build output. Sample script for XAML builds available [here](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Scripts/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1)